# Get all Cells from UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am wanting to get **ALL** cells from a `UITableView`, I understand `tableView.visableCells` will return an array of the cells visible on the screen but I am needing to get **ALL** cells.

The below is roughly how I plan to achieve this however I cannot workout how to get **ALL** cells, not just the visible cells. Users will be able to reorder the `UITableView` cells and I want to be able to record the index of each cell once they have moved the `UITableViewCell` which is why I need all cells

```
var textArray : [String] = [] // This is populated elsewhere and contains 30+ items
var textDict = [String:String]()


// allCellIndexPaths is a placeholder. I need to know how to get all Cell IndexPaths
for cellIndex in allCellIndexPaths { 
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: cellIndex)
    let text = cell.textLabel.text
    textDict["Cell \(cellIndex.row)"] = text
}
```

the reason for wanting this is I am saving `textDict` to a file so that when the user reorders the cells, I am saving their new index, I then can load the content in order of the index values I have saved even once the app has been completely closed and reopened. This is also why I cannot just record the value of the `sourceIndexPath` and `destinationIndexPath` because that could result in 2 indexes the same in my dict, thats why I want to get a list of each cell index and its text.

Absolutely open to a better way to do this

Comment: Cells are simply a view of your underlying data model. Since cells are just a view you can only get cells for rows that are actually visible.  It isn't possible to get a cell for a row that isn't onscreen. You should reorder `textArray` when your table is reordered and you shouldn't need to read text from a cell; it is already in your array. There is no need for `textDict` since it is essentially an array - its key is the string version of the row ordinal.

Comment: @Paulw11 the reason for wanting this is I am saving `textDict` to a file so that when the user reorders the cells, I am saving their new index, I then can load the content in order of the index values I have saved even once the app has been completely closed and reopened. This is also why I cannot just record the value of the `sourceIndexPath` and `destinationIndexPath` because that could result in 2 indexes the same in my dict, thats why I want to get a list of each cell index and its text.

Comment: But you can just save the array. A dictionary with a integer key (or in your case a string representation of an integer) is just an array (except that a dictionary could handle sparseness but that isn’t a requirement here). Regardless you only need to update the two relevant keys in the dictionary. You can’t have two entries with the same key. That isn’t how dictionaries work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need all cell you to implement reorder cell. You just need to map the reorder indexpath correctly. Below is link which has the correct example to do reorder cell.
https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/reorderable-cells/

you need to make table in editing mode

```
self.tableView.isEditing = true
```

If you want to hide the delete button in editing mode use :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .none
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}
```

Enable the reorder control to move cells by overwriting tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath: and implement the method so that the elements in the underlying data list are updated:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedObject = self.headlines[sourceIndexPath.row]
    headlines.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    headlines.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: Yes I’m already doing that but once I have reordered the cells I want to save the index of every cell so that when I reopen the app I can call it back in the order it was changed to

Comment: There are ways to that as. You can logic to show where you want to show, tableview will follow you and as per data source. Another way is State Restoration.